# Array doesn't contain all values from DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a problem with php array which I haven't seen before. I'm fetching data from DB and building an array so I could transfer all data to another DB. My problem is that I have around 100K rows to put in array and transfer it, but in the end my array contains only 12 rows.
There is no error reported and everything finishes OK, but with 12 records instead of 100K.

Please, take a look at my code and point me to the problem. I have spent days and I cant figure it out. Is there any limitations on array or whatever?

Also I have increased max memory and max execution time on my dev server so it doesn't make any problems for me, but it didn't help.

```
    <?php
include("../includes/session.php");

//Here we set connection to Gimli MySQL server
//Connect to DPB DB
$servername = "X";
$username = "X";
$database = "X";
$password = "X";

//  Create a new connection to the MySQL
$conn_gimli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn_gimli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn_gimli->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully<br>";
}

//Get pricelist headers from iManage pricelist
$pricelist_header = array();
if($stmt = $conn_gimli -> prepare("SELECT id, YEAR(vrijeme), naziv FROM servis.kalkulacija_import_cjenik")) {
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $stmt -> bind_result($pricelist_id, $pricelist_year, $pricelist_name);
    while($stmt ->fetch()) {
        $pricelist_header[] = array('header_year' => $pricelist_year,
                                    'header_name' => $pricelist_name,
                                    'header_id' => $pricelist_id);
    }
} else {
    $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
    echo $error;
    die;
}

//Get pricelist items from iManage pricelist
foreach($pricelist_header as $key => $value) {
    $pricelist_items = array();
    if($stmt = $conn_gimli -> prepare("SELECT id_cjenika, godina, kataloski_broj, naziv, cijena_EUR, valuta FROM servis.kalkulacija_import_cjenik_stavke WHERE id_cjenika = ?")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param("i", $value['header_id']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmt -> bind_result($item_id, $item_year, $item_article_no, $item_name, $item_price, $item_currency);
        while($stmt -> fetch()) {
            $pricelist_items[] = array('item_id' => $item_id,
                                        'item_year' => $item_year,
                                        'item_article_no' => $item_article_no,
                                        'item_name' => $item_name,
                                        'item_price' => decimal_convert($item_price),
                                        'item_currency' => $item_currency);
        }
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
        echo $error;
        die;
    }
}

//View arrays
//var_dump($pricelist_header);
//var_dump($pricelist_items);


//Insert headers and items in DB
foreach($pricelist_header as $key => $value) {
    //Insert header and get inserted id
    if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO dpb.calculation_pricelist (name, for_year) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param("si", $value['header_name'], $value['header_year']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $last_id = $stmt -> insert_id;
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
        echo $error;
        die;
    }

    if(!empty($last_id)) {
        foreach($pricelist_items as $ikey => $ivalue) {
            //Insert items for header
            if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO dpb.calculation_pricelist_articles (pricelist_id, article_no, description, normal_price, currency) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $stmt -> bind_param("issis", $last_id, $ivalue['item_article_no'], $ivalue['item_name'], $ivalue['item_price'], $ivalue['item_currency']);
                $stmt -> execute();
                $stmt -> close();
            } else {
                $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
                echo $error;
                die;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably want this before the loop, and not inside the loop: `$pricelist_items = array();`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few errors, and while I have rewritten the code in a format I believe will work for you, I believe the error equally could have been that you forgot to close a connection, so it wouldn't iterate through every value, only one. And so perhaps by 12 rows, you were actually getting 6 key => value pairs (6*2).
Although that is a bit of wild speculation on my part, and would depend on how you were determining your code wasn't working.

The following code should work for you instead :

```
//Get pricelist headers from iManage pricelist
$pricelist_header = array();
if($stmt = $conn_gimli -> prepare("SELECT id, YEAR(vrijeme), naziv FROM servis.kalkulacija_import_cjenik")) {
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $stmt -> bind_result($pricelist_id, $pricelist_year, $pricelist_name);
    while($stmt ->fetch()) {
    // We push the values to our array, rather than re-declaring it.
    array_push($pricelist_header, array('header_year' => $pricelist_year,
                                        'header_name' => $pricelist_name,
                                        'header_id' => $pricelist_id);         
        }
    } 

    else {
    $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
    die($error);
}
$stmt->close(); // This was where you forgot to close the connection.

// ****** Removed a duplicate block of code, here. *****

// Declare array outside of loop.
$pricelist_items = array();

//Get pricelist items from iManage pricelist
foreach($pricelist_header as $key => $value) {

    if($stmt = $conn_gimli -> prepare("SELECT id_cjenika, godina, kataloski_broj, naziv, cijena_EUR, valuta FROM servis.kalkulacija_import_cjenik_stavke WHERE id_cjenika = ?")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param("i", $value['header_id']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmt -> bind_result($item_id, $item_year, $item_article_no, $item_name, $item_price, $item_currency);
        while($stmt -> fetch()) {
        // We push the values to our array, rather than re-declaring it.

        array_push($pricelist_items, array('item_id' => $item_id,
                                            'item_year' => $item_year,
                                            'item_article_no' => $item_article_no,
                                            'item_name' => $item_name,
                                            'item_price' => decimal_convert($item_price),
                                            'item_currency' => $item_currency);

        }
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
        die($error);
    }
}

// Declare array outside of your loop
$pricelist_items = array();

//Get pricelist items from iManage pricelist
foreach($pricelist_header as $key => $value) {        
    if($stmt = $conn_gimli -> prepare("SELECT id_cjenika, godina, kataloski_broj, naziv, cijena_EUR, valuta FROM servis.kalkulacija_import_cjenik_stavke WHERE id_cjenika = ?")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param("i", $value['header_id']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $stmt -> bind_result($item_id, $item_year, $item_article_no, $item_name, $item_price, $item_currency);
        while($stmt -> fetch()) {
            // We push the values to our array, rather than re-declaring it.
            array_push($pricelist_items, array('item_id' => $item_id,
                                        'item_year' => $item_year,
                                        'item_article_no' => $item_article_no,
                                        'item_name' => $item_name,
                                        'item_price' => decimal_convert($item_price),
                                        'item_currency' => $item_currency);
        }
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
        die($error);
    }
}

//View arrays
//var_dump($pricelist_header);
//var_dump($pricelist_items);


//Insert headers and items in DB
foreach($pricelist_header as $key => $value) {
    //Insert header and get inserted id
    if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO dpb.calculation_pricelist (name, for_year) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param("si", $value['header_name'], $value['header_year']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $last_id = $stmt -> insert_id;
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
        die($error);
    }

    if(!empty($last_id)) {
       // There was a spelling error here, instead of $key it said $ikey
        foreach($pricelist_items as $key => $ivalue) {
            //Insert items for header
            if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO dpb.calculation_pricelist_articles (pricelist_id, article_no, description, normal_price, currency) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $stmt -> bind_param("issis", $last_id, $ivalue['item_article_no'], $ivalue['item_name'], $ivalue['item_price'], $ivalue['item_currency']);
                $stmt -> execute();
                $stmt -> close();
            } else {
                $error = $conn -> errno . ' ' . $conn -> error;
                die($error);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Describing what you changed and why would be helpful instead of just posting a code block.

Comment: @rpm192 Yes that's correct, I was posting the codeblock to allow the user a solution, and then I could return to edit and include documentation, when I had a more opportune time.